# Add elements of 2d array in C++

Tags: c++

I have this 2d array:

```
vector<vector<int>> arr = {{1, 1}, 
                           {1, 3, 2}, 
                           {1, 6, 11, 6}};
```

I want to add the lasts elements of each row (1 + 2 + 6), and then the second-lasts (1 + 3 + 11), and so on ((1 + 6), (1)). How can I do that?

Btw sorry for my english (not native speaker).

Comment: This doesn't look like a matrix, nomatter how you interpret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by, for example,

1. Calculate the maximum number of elements of the elements of `arr`.
2. Iterate from `0` to the maximum number minus one.
3. Retrieve the `i`th element counted from the last element with checking if the element has `i` element or more.
4. Add the elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int main(void) {
    vector<vector<int>> arr = {{1, 1}, 
                               {1, 3, 2}, 
                               {1, 6, 11, 6}};

    size_t max_num = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if (max_num < arr[i].size()) max_num = arr[i].size();
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max_num; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
            if (i < arr[j].size()) sum += arr[j][arr[j].size() - 1 - i];
        }
        std::cout << sum << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```